# Compare roots of quadratic functions

Tags: c++, optimization, algebra

I need function to fast compare root of quadratic function and a given value and function to fast compare two roots of two quadratic functions.

I write first function

```
bool isRootLessThanValue (bool sqrtDeltaSign, int a, int b, int c, int value) {
    bool ret;

    if(sqrtDeltaSign){
        if(a < 0){
            ret = (2*a*value + b < 0) || (a*value*value + b*value + c > 0);
        }else{
            ret = (2*a*value + b > 0) && (a*value*value + b*value + c > 0);
        }
    }else{
        if(a < 0){
            ret = (2*a*value + b < 0) && (a*value*value + b*value + c < 0);
        }else{
            ret = (2*a*value + b > 0) || (a*value*value + b*value + c < 0);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

When i try to write this for second function it grow to very big and complicated...

```
bool isRoot1LessThanRoot2 (bool sqrtDeltaSign1, int a1, int b1, int c1, bool sqrtDeltaSign2, int a2, int b2, int c2) {
    //...
}
```

Have u any suggestions how can i simplify this function?

If you think thats stupid idea for optimizations, please tell me why :)

Comment: You might probably want a dedicated class for quadratic formula.

Comment: Quadratic formula might have 2 roots, unclear what you want to compare (first snippet seems to compare `value` to `x1` or `x2` (depending of boolean), second snippet is even less clear).

Comment: you are using different combinations of similar conditions in alll branches. Code will be more readable if you give those terms names and use those names in the branches instead of repeating the expressions. Thats readability, what do you want to optimize for? Runtime?

Comment: also you can remove `ret` and simply write `return ...` instead of `ret = ...`. The less code one has to read to understand what a single line does the less complex is the code

Comment: for a review of working code you can ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Just make sure to post complete and correct code there and to remove the question here in case you post there

Comment: i need only this one function (with only one call) so im not sure if i want class for this.
im not sure if i want function for this

Comment: how often you call it isnt that relevant for whether you write a function or a class. When you use a class it is easier to split it in smaller simple parts and hide that complexity from the caller

Comment: You have the same expression in multiple places. That's inefficient. At first glance, I would create temporaries for `a*value` and `b*value` so they don't have to be recomputed each time they appear.

Comment: If I understood your optimization, you were avoiding to use math square root function to calculate the roots. But I don't think this much complicate coding will be fast than a single square root function. A simple test may solve this myth.

Comment: @GinDev01: can you explain what you're trying to do here? As far as I know, a quadratic equation is of the form `ax^2+bx+c=0`, where `a`, `b` and `c` all can be real numbers (floating point, `double` in programming). What's the meaning of `value`? Do you mean that you have different roots and that you want to check if the value is below, above or in between of the roots? ...

Comment: @ytlu correct :) this optimization is for two reasons 
1. fast (it isnt use sqrt() function)
2. stability (it isnt use double)

im close to write simple benchmark

Comment: @Dominique i calculate a, b and c from integers, so it will be integer

Comment: @GinDev01 A very quick improvement is made your quadratic function standard: f(x) = x^2 + 2 B x + C, where B = b/2a and C = c/a. This reduces three parameters to two without extra costs. (Edit:  No, I forgot your insistency in using integers.)

Comment: For execution your code is efficient because there is only one calculation that is performed.  For space efficiency, there is a lot of redundancy.  The only optimization I see is that `a*value` is used twice in the calculations; so you should store the result of `a*value` in a constant temporary variable.

Comment: I recommend that you make the calculations first and store the results into separate constant temporary variables.  Processors love data processing and math instructions; so there is no efficiency loss by do this.  However, comparisons and branches annoy and irritate processors.  The processor has to decide which path to take and whether or not to reload the instruction cache or pipeline; time that could be spent processing data instructions.

Comment: Serval questions reading your post:  --- 1. What is the meaning of bool sqrtDeltaSign? It seems that you assign a negative sign to sqrt(Delta), sometimes?   ---- 2. And when delta is negative, there are no root at all. How to compare root with the given value?  ---- 3. There is usaully two roots, which is used to compare with the value?

Comment: Code like `a*value*value` limits the useful range of `a, value` to about 11 bits.  Else code has UB. GinDev01, what are the ranges of `a,b,c,value`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica if i would larger range of variables i will use long long type.
But thats good question. i dont know how to fix that problem (using full range of variables type)

Comment: Using `long long` and `a*value*value` only good to about 21 bit.  Still, unanswered, what range are you using?  8-bit?

Comment: @ytlu
sqrtDeltaSign is a sign in equation
x1 = (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
x2 = (-b + sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
thats mean which root (x1 or x2) is on a scene

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica a, b and c are calculating from points coordinates. i would use a 64-bit range values. "how to do it" thats my next question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I give a simpified version of the first part of your code by comparing the greater root of the quadratic function with a given value as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // for main testing
int isRootLessThanValue (int a, int b, int c, int value)
  {
    if (a<0){ b *= -1;  c *= -1;   a *= -1;}
    int xt, delta;
    xt = 2 * a * value + b;
    if (xt < 0) return false; // value is left to reflection point
    delta = b*b - 4*a*c;
 // compare square distance between value and the root
    return  ( (xt * xt) > delta )? true: false;
  }
```

In the test main() program, the roots are first calculate for clarity purpose:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, v;

    a = -2;
    b = 4;
    c = 3;
    double r1, r2, r, dt;
    dt  = std::sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*c);
    r1 = (-b + dt) / (2.0*a);
    r2 = (-b - dt) / (2.0*a);
    r = (r1>r2)? r1 : r2;
    while (1)
    {
       std::cout << "Input the try value = ";
       std::cin >> v;
       if (isRootLessThanValue(a,b,c,v)) std::cout << v <<" > " << r << std::endl;
       else std::cout << v <<" < " << r  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

A test run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are definitely talking micro-optimization here, but consider making calculations before performing the comparison:

```
bool isRootLessThanValue (bool sqrtDeltaSign, int a, int b, int c, int value)
{
    const int a_value = a * value;
    const int two_a_b_value = 2 * a_value + b;
    const int a_squared_b = a_value * value + b * value + c;
    const bool two_ab_less_zero = (two_a_b_value < 0);
    bool ret = false;
    if(sqrtDeltaSign)
    {
        const bool a_squared_b_greater_zero = (a_squared_b > 0);
        if (a < 0)
        {
            ret = two_ab_less_zero || a_squared_b_greater_zero;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = !two_ab_less_zero && a_squared_b_greater_zero;//(edited)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const bool a_squared_b_less_zero = (a_squared_b < 0);
        if (a < 0)
        {
            ret = two_ab_less_zero && a_squared_b_less_zero;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = !two_ab_less_zero || a_squared_b_less_zero;//(edited)
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Another note, is that the boolean expression is calculated and stored in a variable, thus could be counted as a data processing instruction (depending on the compiler and processor).

Compare the assembly language of this function to yours.  Also benchmark.  As I said, I'm not expecting much time savings here, but I don't know how many times this function is called in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that both quadratics have real, mutually distinct roots, and `a1 = a2 = 1`. This keeps the notations simpler, though similar logic can be used in the general case.

Suppose `f(x) = x^2 + b1 x + c1` has the real roots `u1 < u2`, and `g(x) = x^2 + b2 x + c2` has the real roots `v1 < v2`. Then there are 6 possible sort orders.

- **(1)**   `u1 < u2 < v1 < v2`
- **(2)**   `u1 < v1 < u2 < v2`
- **(3)**   `u1 < v1 < v2 < u2`
- **(4)**   `v1 < u1 < u2 < v2`
- **(5)**   `v1 < u1 < v2 < u2`
- **(6)**   `v1 < v2 < u1 < u2`

Let `v` be a root of `g` so that `g(v) = v^2 + b2 v + c2 = 0` then `v^2 = -b2 v - c2` and therefore `f(v) = (b1 - b2) v + c1 - c2 = b12 v + c12` where `b12 = b1 - b2` and `c12 = c1 - c2`.

It follows that `Sf = f(v1) + f(v2) = b12(v1 + v2) + 2 c12` and `Pf = f(v1) f(v2) = b12^2 v1 v2 + b12 c12 (v1 + v2) + c12^2`. Using [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Vieta%27s%20formulas%20are,are%20used%20specifically%20in%20algebra.) `v1 v2 = c2` and `v1 + v2 = -b2` so in the end `Sf = f(v1) + f(v2) = -b12 b2 + 2 c2` and `Pf = f(v1) f(v2) = b12^2 c2 - b12 c12 b2 + c12^2`. Similar expressions can be calculated for `Sg = g(u1) + g(u2)` and `Pg = g(u1) g(u2)`.

(*Should be noted that `Sf, Pf, Sg, Pg` above are arithmetic expressions in the coefficients, not involving `sqrt` square roots. There is, however, the potential for integer overflow. If that is an actual concern, then the calculations would have to be done in floating point instead of integers.*)

- If `Pf = f(v1) f(v2) < 0` then exactly one root of `f` is between the roots `v1, v2` of `g`.

  - If the axis of `f` is to the left of the `g` one, meaning `-b1 < -b2`, then that's the smaller root `u1` of `f` which is between `v1, v2` i.e. case **(5)**.
  - Otherwise if `-b1 > -b2` then that's the larger root i.e. case **(2)**.
- If `Pf = f(v1) f(v2) > 0` then either both or none of the roots of `f` are between the roots of `g`. In this case `f(v1)` and `f(v2)` must have the same sign, and they will either be both negative if `Sf = f(v1) + f(v2) < 0` or both positive if `Sf > 0`.

  - If `f(v1) < 0` and `f(v2) < 0` then both roots `v1, v2` of `g` are between the roots of `f` i.e. case **(3)**.
  - By symmetry, if `Pg > 0` and `Sg < 0` then `g(u1) < 0` and `g(u2) < 0`, so both roots `u1, u2` of `f` are between the roots of `g` i.e. case **(4)**.
  - Otherwise the last combination left is `f(v1), f(v2) > 0` and `g(u1), g(u2) > 0` where the intervals `(u1, u2)` and `(v1, v2)` do not overlap. If `-b1 < -b2` the axis of `f` is to the left of the `g` one i.e. case **(1)** else it's case **(6)**.

Once the sort order between all roots is determined, comparing any particular pair of roots follows.

Answer (score 0):

Im reorganising my code and have found some facilities :)

When calculate a, b and c i can keep structure to get only a > 0 :)
and i know that i want small or big root :)

so function to compare root to value is regresed  to the form below

```
bool isRootMinLessThanValue (int a, int b, int c, int value) {
    const int a_value = a * value;
    const int u = 2*a_value + b;
    const int v = a_value*value + b*value + c;
    
    return u > 0 || v < 0 ;
};
bool isRootMaxLessThanValue (int a, int b, int c, int value) {
    const int a_value = a*value;
    const int u = 2*a_value + b;
    const int v = a_value*value + b*value + c;
    
    return u > 0 && v > 0;
}
```

when im testing benchmark its faster than calculate roots traditionaly (by assumptions I cannot say how much)

Below code for fast (and slow traditionaly) compare root to value without assumptions

```
bool isRootLessThanValue (bool sqrtDeltaSign, int a, int b, int c, int value) {
    const int a_value = a*value;
    const int u = 2*a_value + b;
    const int v = a_value*value + b*value + c;
    const bool s = sqrtDeltaSign;
    
    return      (  a < 0  &&  s && u < 0 ) || 
                (  a < 0  &&  s && v > 0 ) || 
                (  a < 0  && !s && u < 0 && v < 0) ||
                (!(a < 0) && !s && u > 0 ) ||
                (!(a < 0) && !s && v < 0 ) ||
                (!(a < 0) &&  s && u > 0 && v > 0);
};
bool isRootLessThanValueTraditional (bool sqrtDeltaSign, int a, int b, int c, int value) {
    double delta = b*b - 4.0*a*c;
    double calculatedRoot = sqrtDeltaSign ? (-b + sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a) : (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2.0*a);
    return calculatedRoot < value;
};
```

benchmark results below:

- isRootLessThanValue (optimized): 10000000000 compares in 152.922s
- isRootLessThanValueTraditional : 10000000000 compares in 196.168s

Any suggestions how can i simplify even more isRootLessThanValue function? :)

I will try to prepare function to compare two roots of different equations

edited::2020-11-30

```
bool isRootLessThanValue (bool sqrtDeltaSign, int a, int b, int c, int value) {
const int a_value = a*value;
const int u = 2*a_value + b;
const int v = a_value*value + b*value + c;

return  sqrtDeltaSign ? 
    (( a < 0 && (u < 0 || v > 0) ) || (u > 0 && v > 0)) :
    (( a > 0 && (u > 0 || v < 0) ) || (u < 0 && v < 0));
```

};

Comment: You should make it more clear in the question what exactly is it that you are after. The title says  "*compare roots of quadratic functions*" but that does not require to "*compare root to value*", which is what's done here.

Comment: Well, you didn't accept other answers, either ;-) which solved the former without requiring the latter, so it's still not too clear what kind of answers the question is looking for. P.S. Your last `return` would be a bit more readable IMHO if written as `return sqrtDeltaSign ? (...) : (...);`.

Comment: i want to show function for compare roots (i have very dirty version) so when I'll handle it i give it here, and if comments show me that is good i'll accept answer ;)
Thanks for suggestion;)